# Why does it take a long time to record video to a file?

Tags: c++, windows-ce, directshow

I developed a video capture application in which the CPU is 624MHz(ARM920T-PAX310), and RAM is 72MB. The captured video is 1 minute but it takes almost 10 minutes to save the video file. I set a breakpoint, and found it took a long time.

```
    //------------------- set filename
HRESULT hResult;
    CComPtr<IFileSinkFilter>        pFileSinkFilter;

    m_pMediaControl->Stop();
    m_pMediaControl->Run();
    CHK(m_pASFMultiplexer->QueryInterface(&pFileSinkFilter));   CHK(pFileSinkFilter->SetFileName(L"\\windows\\sample.asf",NULL));// pFileSinkFilter.Release();
//------------------start record
LONGLONG dwStart = 0, dwEnd = 0;
    WORD     wStartCookie = 1, wEndCookie = 2;
    HRESULT hResult = 0;
    if( m_pCaptureGraphBuilder == NULL )
    {
       return FALSE;
    }    
    //
    dwStart=0;
    dwEnd=MAXLONGLONG;
    hResult = m_pCaptureGraphBuilder->ControlStream( &PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE, &MEDIATYPE_Video, m_pVideoCaptureFilter, &dwStart, &dwEnd, wStartCookie, wEndCookie );
Sleep(60000);//1 minute
//------------------stop record
HRESULT   hResult = S_OK;
    LONGLONG  dwStart = 0, dwEnd = 0;
    WORD      wStartCookie = 1, wEndCookie = 2;
    LONG lEventCode = 0;
    LONG lParam1 = 0;
    LONG lParam2 = 0;
    if( m_pCaptureGraphBuilder == NULL )
    {
       return FALSE;
    }
    //
    dwStart = 0;
    hResult = m_pMediaSeeking->GetCurrentPosition( &dwEnd );
    hResult = m_pCaptureGraphBuilder->ControlStream( &PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE, &MEDIATYPE_Video, m_pVideoCaptureFilter, &dwStart, &dwEnd, wStartCookie, wEndCookie );
    //
    while (true)
    {
        m_pMediaEvent->GetEvent( &lEventCode, &lParam1, &lParam2, INFINITE );
        m_pMediaEvent->FreeEventParams( lEventCode, lParam1, lParam2 );
        if( lEventCode == EC_STREAM_CONTROL_STOPPED ) {
            TRACE(L"Record stop\n");
            break;
        }
        Sleep(100);
        NKDbgPrintfW(L"lEventCode = %d dwEnd = %d\n",lEventCode,dwEnd);
    }
```

I found file's size increase continous from "start record ". Why does it take a long time for "stop record" What should I do in "stop record"???

Comment: Sure it is only the stop method taking so long? Because the ASF-Mux also encodes the Video/Audio stream. And encoding with this low CPU and RAM can take some time. You can try a different profile for the Encoding or try to capture to avi without encoding. I have also seen problems with the writing speed for hard drives for big video sizes.

Comment: i use this code ,but return E_FAIL,strFileName=L"\\Storage Card\\aaaa.avi";
 CHK(m_pCaptureGraphBuilder->SetOutputFileName( &MEDIASUBTYPE_Avi,strFileName, &m_pASFMultiplexer, &pFileSinkFilter ));//